# Will these two kangaroos meet ever?

Tags: mathematics

We have two Kangaroos. First one starts from point S1 and jumps for distance D1 in one jump. Second one starts from point S2 and jumps for distance D2 in one jump. Both will jump along the number line, S1 and S2 both are positive numbers on the number line.

Comment: What do you want?  We can't really tell if the kangaroos meet unless you give us S1, etc. and the directions they hop in.  Do you want a criteria for determining if they meet or something?

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Is this an original problem of yours? If not, could you please post a reference?

Comment: greenturtle3141 & Oray, I think the problem with this question is not that it is unclear or underdetermined. It is easy to come up with exact criteria to answer the question in the title. In my opinion this is a standard problem, which is not original and hardly qualifies as a puzzle.

Comment: A simple websearch gives lot of copies of this problem, e.g.: https://www.codechef.com/problems/JMPKANG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is basically asking for when 2 Arithmetic Progressions intersect, for which a detail solution can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1656138)

Comment: I wanted to post that as a comment, I dunno why it got posted as an answer. Oh well...

Comment: That answers the much more difficult question of finding places that both kangaroos visit, not necessarily at the same time. Finding out whether they ever land in the same spot at the same time is almost trivial, yet that seems to be what this question is asking for (given that it is [this codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/JMPKANG) that elias found). Solving that is just finding the intersection of two lines, and checking whether it happens after a whole number of jumps.